# Is it possible to load an image inline from camera in JS?

Tags: javascript, svg, camera

Is it possible, using javascript, to allow a user to take a picture with their device and embed it into a svg for further processing without uploading image to a server? I'd like to allow a user to take a picture with their device, display it in an svg element so they can add annotations. Once they are done, they could push the whole svg, including the embedded image to the server.

Answer (score 0):

It depends where the javascript is running. With HTML5 you can grab a files contents prior to it being uploaded [using the FileAPI](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/) and there are libraries available that will convert an image to SVG, the problem you have is with gaining access to the camera.

- In a users browser? No, you don't have access to their camera without utilizing Flash/Java
- In a Cordova mobile app? Yes, you can gain access to the users camera.
- In a [Chrome App](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps)? Yes, you can get access to a lot of low-level APIs via Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is the new JavaScript API getUserMedia/Stream API:

http://caniuse.com/#feat=stream[1](http://caniuse.com/#feat=stream)